# Attempting to provide github credentials to jenkins pipeline job

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to set up the credentials for github in a jenkins pipeline job. I have the following in my pipeline script:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    git([url: 'ssh://git@github.com/user/repname/', branch: 'master', credentialsId: 'xxx-xxx-xxx'])
```

Where does the credentialsId come from? Is this created elsewhere in Jenkins?

Update: 
I pulled the credentials id from this page:
[image]

But now I am seeing this error:

> Started by user anonymous
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:
>   startup failed: WorkflowScript: 3: Undefined section "git" @ line 3,
>   column 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you found yourself, it's the credentials id provided in the credentials view.

Now, as for your second problem, you're using declarative pipeline, it requires that you have the following structure:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                git([url: 'ssh://git@github.com/user/repname/', branch: 'master', credentialsId: 'xxx-xxx-xxx'])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

E.g. you need to put the `git` step insde of the `stages`, `stage` and `steps` clauses ([documentation of this can be found here](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-pipeline)).

Alternatively you can use scripted pipeline, then it becomes:

```
node {
    git([url: 'ssh://git@github.com/user/repname/', branch: 'master', credentialsId: 'xxx-xxx-xxx'])
}
```

However, when you're creating simple pipelines, then declarative pipelines provides a lot of nice to have features. [See my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42051069/7509826) for a comparison between declarative and scripted pipelines.

Comment: Thanks, that got me past that error. Now on to the next one :)