# Jenkins Pipeline: Are agents required to utilize Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, agent

I am investigating the use of Jenkins Pipeline (specifically using Jenkinsfile). The context of my implementation is that I'm deploying a Jenkins instance using Chef. Part of this deployment may include some seed jobs, which will pull job configurations from source control (Jenkinsfile), to automate creation of our build jobs via Chef.

I've investigated the Jenkins documentation for both [Pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/) as well as [Jenkinsfile](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/), and it seems to me that in order to use Jenkins Pipeline agents are required to be configured and set up in addition to Jenkins Master.

Am I understanding this correctly? Must Jenkins agents exist in order to use Jenkins Pipeline's Jenkinsfile? This specific line in the Jenkinsfile documentation leads me to believe this to be true:

```
Jenkinsfile (Declarative Pipeline)
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo 'Building..'
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                echo 'Testing..'
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                echo 'Deploying....'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> The Declarative Pipeline example above contains the minimum necessary
> structure to implement a continuous delivery pipeline. The agent
> directive, which is required, instructs Jenkins to allocate an
> executor and workspace for the Pipeline.

Thanks in advance for any Jenkins guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The '`agent`' part of the pipeline is required however this does not mean that you are required to have an external agent in addition to your master. If all you have is the master this pipeline will execute on the master. If you have additional agents available the pipeline would execute on whichever agent happens to be available when you run the pipeline.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Makes sense with everything I've seen in the Jenkins documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you go into
Manage Jenkins -> Manage Nodes and Clouds, you can see 'Master' itself is treated as one of the Default Nodes. With declarative format `agent any`indicates any available agent which (including 'Master' as well from node configuration see below).

[image]

In case if you configure any New node, this can then be treated as New Agent in the pipeline `agent any` can be replaced by `agent 'Node_Name'`

You may can refer this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42050626/jenkins-pipeline-agent-vs-node) which give hint on Agent, Node and Slave briefly.