# Do I have to use a node block in Declarative Jenkins pipelines?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I was reading about the best practices of a Jenkins pipeline.
I have created a declarative pipeline which is not executing parallel jobs and I want to run everything on the same slave.

I use:

```
agent {
    label 'xxx'
}
```

The rest of my pipeline looks like:

```
pipeline {
        agent {
            label 'xxx'
        }
    triggers {
        pollSCM pipelineParams.polling
    }

    options {
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '3'))
    }

    stages {
        stage('stage1') {
            steps {
                xxx
            }
        }

        stage('stage2') {
            steps {
                xxx
            }
        }
    }

    post {
        always {
            cleanWs()
        }

        failure {
            xxx"
        }

        success {
            xxx         
        }
    }
}
```

Now I read the best practices [here](https://dzone.com/articles/top-10-best-practices-for-jenkins-pipeline).
Point 4 is telling:

> 4. Do: All Material Work Within a Node
>
> Any material work within a pipeline should occur within a node block.
>
> Why? By default, the Jenkinsfile script itself runs on the Jenkins
>   master, using a lightweight executor expected to use very few
>   resources. Any material work, like cloning code from a Git server or
>   compiling a Java application, should leverage Jenkins distributed
>   builds capability and run an agent node.

I suspect this is for scripted pipelines.

Now my questions are:

Do I ever have to create a `node` inside a `stage` in a declarative pipeline (it is possible) or do I have to use agent inside the stage when I want to run my stage on another specific agent?

My current pipeline has defined a `label` which is on 4 agents. But my whole pipeline is always executed on one agent (what I want) but I would suspect it's executing `stage1` on `slaveX` and maybe `stage2` on `slaveY`. Why is this not happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jenkins pipeline: agent vs node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42050626/jenkins-pipeline-agent-vs-node)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation is quite misleading.

What the documentation is suggesting is to take advantage of distributed builds. Distributed builds activated either by using the `agent` or `node` block.
The `agent` should be used when you want to run the pipeline almost exclusively on one node. The node block allows for more flexibilty as it allows you to specify where a granular task should be executed.

If you running the pipeline on some agent and you encapsulate a step with node with the same agent, there won't be any effect execpt that a new executor will be allocated to the step encapsulated with node.
There is no obvious benefit in doing so. You will simply be consuming executors that you don't need.

In conclusion, you are already using distributed builds when using `agent` and this is what the documentation is vaguely recommending.