# Run Jenkins parallel stages across different nodes using declarative syntax

Tags: jenkins, parallel-processing, jenkins-pipeline, distributed

Managed to successfully run integration tests in parallel on the same node and I now I would like to distribute them across different nodes. In the example below I want stages `IT 1` and `IT 2` to run on different nodes leaving `IT 3` to run on the original node. Tried several combinations by using `node` as a parent of `stage('IT 1')` and `node` as a child but I get syntax errors for both. What is the proper syntax to achieve this?

```
pipeline {

  agent { label '!master' }

  stages {
    stage('Integration Tests') {
      parallel {
        stage('IT 1 (slow)') {
          steps {
            sh 'run-it-1.sh'
          }
        }
        stage('IT 2 (slow)') {
          steps {
            sh 'run-it-2.sh'
          }
        }
        stage('IT 3 (quick)') {
          steps {
            sh 'run-it-3.sh'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Edit: Using `label` instead of `node` works for declarative pipelines. Example below:

```
stage('IT 1 (slow)') {
  agent { label '!master' }
  steps {
    sh 'run-it-1.sh'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Declarative version 1.2, you can directly declare the kind of agent you want to use for each parallel stages : https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/09/25/declarative-1/

Not tested this specific use case, but I assume that if you don't declare any *agent{}* for stage "IT 3", it will be executed on the original node.

Hopefully it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still trying to confirm it but my issue seems to come from using `node` instead of `label`. From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42050626/jenkins-pipeline-agent-vs-node: _"Agent is for declarative pipelines and node is for scripted pipelines"_.