# How to declare many agents in a Jenkinsfile with Declarative syntax?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

In the Pipeline scripted syntax we use this syntax to declare specific steps to specific nodes:

```groovy
steps{
    node('node1'){
        // sh
    }
    node('node2'){
        // sh
    }
}
```

But I want to use the [Pipeline Declarative Syntax](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/), can I put many agents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure you can. Just take a look at example (from [docs](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#using-multiple-agents)):

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            agent any
            steps {
                checkout scm
                sh 'make'
                stash includes: '**/target/*.jar', name: 'app' 
            }
        }
        stage('Test on Linux') {
            agent { 
                label 'linux'
            }
            steps {
                unstash 'app' 
                sh 'make check'
            }
            post {
                always {
                    junit '**/target/*.xml'
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Test on Windows') {
            agent {
                label 'windows'
            }
            steps {
                unstash 'app'
                bat 'make check' 
            }
            post {
                always {
                    junit '**/target/*.xml'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, is agent in declarative syntax equivalent to node in scripted syntax? I saw in the documentation that node just adds additional options (such as customWorkspace)

Comment: Yes. But you need to define your build steps in `steps`, while in scripted syntax they are just defined inside of `node`.  You can toggle declarative/scripted syntax in examples in docs, just take a look at the differences.

Comment: Also, [agent vs node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42050626/jenkins-pipeline-agent-vs-node)