# Jenkins: agent vs agent/node

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In Jenkins about to define an agent is possible use either:

#1

```
agent {
    label 'something'
}
```

#2

```
agent {
   node {
      label 'something'
   }
}
```

Both work, but when is mandatory use an approach over the other?

Comment: Should be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42050626/jenkins-pipeline-agent-vs-node

Comment: @MattSchuchard No, it's not. The [docs](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#agent-parameters) are more helpful.

Comment: @MattSchuchard thanks for the link - _it indicates 'but node allows for additional options (such as customWorkspace)'_ - I am going a research about that