# How do I know which stage of jenkins pipeline has failed

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

In my Jenkins pipelines I generally use `post` declarative function to send me an email incase the pipeline has failed.

A simple syntax of the `post` function is as under:

```
post {
    failure {
        mail to: 'team@example.com',
             subject: "Failed Pipeline: ${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}",
             body: "Something is wrong with ${env.BUILD_URL}"
    }
}
```

In the above email, I also want to mention which stage (lets say the pipeline has 5 to 6 stages) of the pipeline has failed. How can I do that? Any help is much appreciated.

An extension to the above requirement will be to provide the user with the actual error log (of the stage that has failed) also as a part of the failure notification email.

Idea is, when a user receives a failure notification from jenkins, he should know which stage of the pipeline has failed along with the error log.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: An alternative is to use "post" at the stage level

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine Failed Stage in Jenkins Declarative Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43439093/determine-failed-stage-in-jenkins-declarative-pipeline). This question has a more comprehensive set of answers.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is a variable called `env.STAGE_NAME` which you can use. However, in your case you will probably need to store the stage name in a different variable, because when you get the `env.STAGE_NAME` in a `post` stage the result will be `Declarative: Post Actions`. Instead, you will need to store the stage name in a variable in all stages. So once a stage fails - Jenkins will not continue with the next stages and therefore you will have the "failed" stage name.

Here's an example:

```
def FAILED_STAGE

pipeline {
    agent { label "master" }
    stages {
        stage("Stage 1") {
            steps {
                script {
                    FAILED_STAGE=env.STAGE_NAME
                    echo "stage 1"
                }
            }
        }
        stage("Stage 2") {
            steps {
                script {
                    FAILED_STAGE=env.STAGE_NAME
                    echo "stage 2"
                    error "failed for some reason."
                }
            }
        }
        stage("Stage 3") {
            steps {
                script {
                    FAILED_STAGE=env.STAGE_NAME
                    echo "stage 3"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        failure {
            echo "Failed stage name: ${FAILED_STAGE}"
        }
    }
}
```

There might be a better way to do it, but I haven't found it so far.

Regarding the logs - As of [JENKINS-40526](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-40526) you could possibly use the API and get the log file from there, but I am not sure you can get the parameters you need from within the pipeline. The other solution would be to use [emailext](https://plugins.jenkins.io/email-ext) and email the entire build log file:

`emailext attachLog: true, body: '', compressLog: true, subject: 'Build failed.', to: 'somebody@somewhere.com'`

Comment: Thanks @tftd for your response. I will try the solution suggested by you and share the feedback.

Comment: Hi @tftd, I'm using `Jenkins ver. 2.41` and in this version, the env variable `STAGE_NAME` is not available. Shall I switch to any specific version of Jenkins for using this env var or there is any other way out?

Comment: This has been fixed in [JENKINS-44456](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-44456) which was released as part of [Pipeline Stage Step Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Stage+Step+Plugin) version 2.3. Check if you can upgrade to that version of the plugin and you should be able to use the env variable.

Comment: Thanks @tftd, after installing the stage step plugin v2.3, I'm able to use `STAGE_NAME` environment variable.

Comment: seems like that `script` tag is needed in order to alter a `def` https://stackoverflow.com/a/39846733/1572848 . you only have it used on step 2 in your example

Comment: @WilliamReed Yeah, that's correct - I've updated the answer. Thanks! :)

Comment: I'm able to echo FAILED_STAGE during the run, but the post-stage doesn't recognize it. I used this syntax: post
    {
        failure {
            emailext body: 'Failed stage name: ${FAILED_STAGE} }}

Comment: Have you defined the variable before the pipeline as in the example?

Comment: Yes I did. maybe something with the apostrophe

Comment: Try using double quotes `"` instead of single ones `'`

Comment: Looks good. However, this may return incorrect stage names when you use parallel stages

Comment: @Kutzi  Yes, the example above is for sequential stage builds. What I tend to do for parallel builds is to approach the issue at a higher level. So for example I have stages like `Checkout`, `Build`, `Test` where `Build` and `Test` have parallel inner stages (i.e. `jdk8`, `jdk11`, etc). When the inner stages fail they will also fail the outer ones (i.e. `Build`). In the failure report you can just mention the `Build` or `Test` (not `jdk8` or `jdk11` because there isn't an easy way to fetch that info)