# Obtain the result for each stage of a jenkins in a variable

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, gitlab-ci, pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a pipeline as such:

```
stages{
 stage ('1') {
  steps{do something}
}

 stage ('2') {
 steps {do something}
}
```

What I would like to do is to get the result of each stage in an environment variable, for example in

```
stage ('1')

        COMPILE_STATUS= <some variable that contains the result of this stage>
        stage ('2')
        TEST_STATUS = <some variable that contains the result of this stage>
```

in the end I would like to customize my email to send out the status of each stage

Comment: There a bunch of questions and answers discussing the use of `currentBuild.currentResult`. You can check those out.

Comment: @MattSchuchard, currentBuild.curretResult gives me the result of the entire build, I am looking for the result of an individual stage within the build and store it in a variable

Comment: I am not aware of "result of stage". The build result is "in progress" until one of the stages fails (the status becomes "aborted"), or the whole build succeeds (so it becomes "success"). For email generation, you can assume stages are successful until the first one that fails.

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/58737417/8895640.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I don't think there is any plugin which hold stage result . I would suggest you to add try catch operation in each stage and post the results accordingly. Let me know if this works.

Comment: I'm trying an approach from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50411381/how-do-i-know-which-stage-of-jenkins-pipeline-has-failed, if I echo the failed stage it works but I'd like to add the failed stage to the emailext body. Would you be able to know how I can do this?