# Jenkins - if statement comparing HOUR is not working

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to add a "validation" stage in Jenkinsfile based on the time. If it is later than 16, validation is required, otherwise not.

the if statement is not working

here I am declaring the variable

```
HOUR=sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'date +"%H"').trim().toInteger()
```

and here is the stage

```
stage('validation') {
  steps {
    script {
      if ( HOUR > 16 ) {
        echo "Validation is required, time now is $HOUR"
      }
      else {
        echo "No validation required, time now is $HOUR"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and here is the output

```
Validation is required, time now is 9
```

the value of the variable HOUR is correct, but the if statement doesnt work correctly

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try first to refer to your variable with the `${xx}` syntax:

```
if ( ${HOUR} > 16 ) {
```

Actually, that would be to be defined in an [environment step](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-model-definition-plugin/wiki/Environment-variables) to be working, as `${env.HOUR}`, as [illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39835712/6309).

---

The [OP Judy1989](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1652397/judy1989) confirms [in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56512820/jenkins-if-statement-comparing-hour-is-not-working/56518176#comment99632648_56518176) that you can use `HOUR`, but in two steps:

```
HOUR=sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'date +"%H"').trim() 
...
if ( HOUR.toInteger() > 16 )
```

You can see an example of such a deferred use [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53722175/6309).

Comment: somehow problem was solved calling ```.toInteger()```in the if statement, doing so ```HOUR=sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'date +"%H"').trim()``` and later ````if ( HOUR.toInteger() > 16 ) ````

Comment: @Judy1989 OK, I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.