# Jenkinsile global variables outside "stages" section

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to set the variable that will be available to all stages. Variable that depends on chosen parameter, something like this:

```
parameters {
      choice(name: 'Environment', choices: ['Dev', 'Stage'], description: 'Deploy to chosen environment')
  }

environment { 
       //set the config file which depends on params.Environment e.g.
       //case params.Environment of
       //   Dev -> CONFIG_FILE="deploy/file_1.conf"
       //   Stage -> CONFIG_FILE="deploy/other_file.conf"
  }

stages {
   stage('check-params') {   
     steps {
        sh "echo \"config file: ${CONFIG_FILE}\""
        }
     }
    stage('build-frontend') {   
     steps {
        sh "build-fronted.sh ${CONFIG_FILE}"
        }
     }
    stage('deploy-backend') {   
     steps {
        sh "deploy-backend.sh ${CONFIG_FILE}"
        }
     }
```

but according to the [Pipeline Syntax](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#environment) it is not allowed (I get *ERROR: Expected name=value pairs*). 
Does anyone know how can I achieve this without using `scripts { ... }` in every stage->step as described [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39832862/jenkins-cannot-define-variable-in-pipeline-stage)?

Comment: If you set a variable in one stage, it will be available in subsequent stages.

Comment: Thanks @MattSchuchard. I fooled myself after reading docs, which says:
`The environment directive specifies a sequence of key-value pairs which will be defined as environment variables for the all steps, or stage-specific steps, depending on where the environment directive is located within the Pipeline.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a init stage which will set correct variable depending on parameter, something like this:

```
parameters {
    choice(name: 'Environment', choices: ['Dev', 'Stage'], description: 'Deploy to chosen environment')
}

environment { 
       //set the config file which depends on params.Environment e.g.
       //case params.Environment of
       //   Dev -> CONFIG_FILE="deploy/file_1.conf"
       //   Stage -> CONFIG_FILE="deploy/other_file.conf"
}

stages {

    // ----------------------------
    stage('init-env-variables') {
        steps {
            script {
                switch(params.Environment) {
                    case "Dev":
                        env.setProperty('CONFIG_FILE', 'deploy/file_1.conf')
                        break;
                    case "Stage":
                        env.setProperty('CONFIG_FILE', 'deploy/other_file.conf')
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // -----------------------

    stage('check-params') {   
        steps {
            sh "echo \"config file: ${CONFIG_FILE}\""
        }
    }
    stage('build-frontend') {   
        steps {
            sh "build-fronted.sh ${CONFIG_FILE}"
        }
    }
    stage('deploy-backend') {   
        steps {
            sh "deploy-backend.sh ${CONFIG_FILE}"
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks [Dumitru](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5539331/dumitru-gurjui)!